# how to *cleanly* switch between git commits

Tags: git, reset

I have been searching for a bit here trying to find a *clear* answer to this question with no luck, so here goes:

- I have a web site with many commits over time
- I want to test the site on an older commit; I want the checkout to reflect the entire site contents as of that commit
- I then want to switch back to the current commit
- I'd like to do this without affecting any of the git history, since I am just flipping between existing commits for testing.

I want to do this without leaving old files from the different commits sitting around when I am done, which git checkout xxxx seems to do.  I assume this is done using --hard, but have been warned about the danger of using this incorrectly.

Having tried this with just 'git checkout xxx', I am left at the end with old files from old commits that were deleted by the latest commit.

Comment: `git checkout` won't alter untracked files. So if you have files that are untracked, they'll sill be there. This is a safety feature.

Comment: Old commits include old files, they are part of the commit. If this answer doesn't help you, tell us some details about what you expect to happen.

Comment: @user2723901 I think you forgot to stash your uncommited changes before doing the `git checkout`, so these changes are still there once checkout is done.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to toggle between old commit and new commit, you can checkout whichever commit you want using `git checkout`.

Another point is there is no `--hard` option in `checkout`, if you meant by `--force`, yes, you need to be careful because force checkout will throw away your local uncommitted modifications.

If you mean `git reset --hard`, you should not use it because your purpose here is not to revert anything from repository.

I would suggest to commit or stash all local changes and then, once you have a clean repository means output of `git status` is clean (that is, empty), then toggle between the current commit and old commits.

Comment: I think they were talking about `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the possibility of git reset too. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `git chekcout` and `git reset` you could try `git worktre`, witch checks out a new worktree that you could toss away when you are done (but it dependes on your stack if you can swith to another workdir)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to checkout an old commit without leaving old files is by creating a new branch from your current branch, checking out an older commit, and then deleting your created branch when you are done looking at the site contents of that commit.

This can be done with:

1. `git checkout -B test_branch`
2. `git checkout <your-old-commit-id>`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git branch -D test_branch`

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not make clear that this request was for working on a server where there are *never* any uncommitted changes.  We only pull new releases (all commits are worked on in a dev environment, and this is a UAT server).  Also, I explicitly wanted the simplest way to switch between releases (commits) ideally without affecting the git history (adding commits, then having to remember to delete them).

By experimentation, this appears to do what I want; let me know if I missed something:

```
   git reset --hard xxxxxxx    #newer git commits and their new files are no longer visible, but they are retained in the .git index
```

When done testing:

```
   git checkout     #resets the environment to the latest commit on this branch with no detritus (obsolete/deleted files)
```